# Laravel 5.4, how to show form fields conditionally?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5.4

I have a form in my Laravel 5.4 app that I would like to hide certain fields unless a particular option is selected from a drop-down box.

I have the following JS script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#stall_id').change(function(){
        if($('#stall-id').val() === '3')
        {
            $('#businessname').show();
            $('#insurance').show();
        } else
        {
            $('#businessname').hide();
            $('#insurance').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

And here is my form fields:

```
<div class="form-group">
  {!! Form::label('businessname', 'Business Name:') !!}
  {!! Form::text('businessname', null, ['id' => 'businessname', 'class'=>'form-control'])!!}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  {!! Form::label('insurance', 'Public Liability Insurance??:') !!}
  {!! Form::label('insurance', 'Yes') !!}
  {!! Form::radio('insurance', 1, ['id' => 'insurance', 'class'=>'form-control'])!!}
  {!! Form::label('insurance', 'No') !!}
  {!! Form::radio('insurance', 0, ['id' => 'insurance', 'class'=>'form-control'])!!}
</div>
```

Those are the form fields I want to be hidden unless the user selects option 3 from the drop-down.
How can this be implemented???
Thanks!

Comment: So, what the question?

Comment: You need to respond to the  `onchange` event on the dropdown check the dropdown's `selectedIndex` to see if its option 3.  Then modify the css for a form group or an individual input element from `display: hidden` to `display:inline`.

Comment: You seem to be using bootstrap. Try adding the `hidden` class then remove accordingly. For example: `$('#businessname').addClass('hidden')`